# Xcode Doesn't Recognize My Device After OS Upgrade

Tags: xcode

This has to be a simple configuration issue, but I don't know my way around the build settings very well.

I upgraded my iPad from 4.3 to 5.0. I am using Xcode 4.2. When I plug my device in, it is not showing up on run button, and I have a message that it can't run using the selected device.

What do I have to do?

Comment: This is the second time I've found my way back to this question, and both times I just needed to restart xcode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open Xcode, go to Window -> Organizer and find your device. Click the "Use for Development" button to get Xcode to recognise it again.

Comment: That was it. I would have never guessed.

Comment: @Luke - I am facing the same problem but now with upgrading from 5.0 to 5.1 but I can't see "User for Development" thing. Plus sometimes it recognize my device and sometimes it don't. Dont know what's the problem. Please help.

Comment: @Luke - I am clicking "Add to Portal" and this is not fixing!

Comment: It just sounds temperamental. Try restarting both the device and Mac, then try device first/then open Xcode, or vice versa. If still nothing, check that the device is at least detected in iTunes, or try again in the Xcode organizer window's device list, either as a grey or green circle should appear next to it's name.

Comment: It sure can be temperamental.  I tried a long cycle of restarting device and Mac, connecting/disconnecting, and restarting Xcode. Finally it started recognizing devices again.  It happened that restarting Xcode did the trick, but I'd already tried that several times before. Perhaps deleting a bunch of no-longer-used devices from the Organizer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

go to your iphone device, settings->Reset->Reset All Settings.  Close Xcode, restart XCode, device should be in the list now.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting USB process worked for me.

Run `sudo pkill usbmuxd` on terminal

**or**

Open **Activity Monitor** and select `Disk` by tapping from segment control and search `usbmuxd`, select the same and force quite/quite.

**Note:** before doing above stuff, remove device and quite Xcode.